# How can I keep the Dark Mech gear/equipment set?

Tags: infinity-blade

You start Bloodline -1 with the Dark Mech armor and gear, but it supposedly disappears upon resetting to Bloodline 1. Is there a way to bring the equipment into the main game? I've read lots of rumors about either purchasing or just getting it at Bloodline -10, but I'd like a definitive answer, perhaps with a screenshot.

Comment: you certainly do not keep it after getting Bloodline -10. I've made it up(down) to Bloodline -11(just to be sure), then restarted the game at Bloodline 1 and... These items disappeared :(

Answer (score 1):

Once you hit negative bloodline ten the get an achievement and you can restart bloodline 1 then you can buy the dark mech gear for millions of dollars per item. An easy way to get this though is to obtain the infinity blade and to to the cave underground and beat the 3 deathless. You don't have to fight the robot after you get the 3 dragoon items just restart bloodline 1 again and fight the deathless again. These 3 items should equal 5 million give or take per bloodline. If you master them though maybe 7 mill hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You must reach over bloodline -10. After that reset to Bloodline 1. They will be in the shop. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to keep the Dark mech gear is: After your done bloodline -9  you have to go to the store, then go to the magic section and then buy THE COG.THE COG looks like the dark halo except it is white.After you buy it, go to bloodline 1 and then check your inventory and it will be there. Only working on I pod 4 and I phone 4. Any questions?